# Segmentation fault when trying to write to .bss

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to write data to space reserved in the `.bss` section of my code (*NASM*/Linux x64). Why do I get segmentation fault in this small code sample?

```
section .bss
  big_space: resb 80         ; reserve 80 bytes

section .text

global _start

_start:
  mov rbx, [rel big_space]   ; I use rel here otherwise I get linking error
  mov [rbx], byte 'H'        ; if I comment this, no segfault

  mov rax, 60                ; exits with code 0
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall
```

Isn't the address of `big_space` supposed to be reserved for my program? As far as I understand, the problematic instruction is trying to copy 'H' (as an 8-bit value) to the address in RBX. This address, as per the first instruction, I expect to be the address of my buffer `big_space`. What went wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `lea rbx, [rel big_space]` ?

Comment: You are right! This worked. I am still curious as to how can I get the relative address of `big_space` into a register using `mov`. I think `mov rbx, rel big_space` doesn't work, nor does `mov eax, qword rel big_space`.

Comment: AFAIK the `rel` specifier is only for effective addresses (something that appears between `[]`).

Comment: @XitoDev To load an address, use `lea` (load effective address).  `mov` is not the right instruction here.

Comment: *how can I get the relative address of big_space into a register using mov* - `mov reg, immediate` needs the absolute address as an immediate so that can't work.  You could also load the correct absolute address from the GOT, if the dynamic linker created a GOT entry for it, like `mov rbx, [rel big_space wrt.. got]` or something (AT&T would be `mov big_space@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rbx`)  https://godbolt.org/z/kUuQes.  You're addressing the GOT entry in a PC-relative way, but still loading an absolute address that has to have been calculated / stored ahead of time.